# AWS Aurora - failed to connect from a MySQL client (Sequel Pro)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, aws-vpc, amazon-aurora

I have set up an AWS Aurora cluster like below:

[image: Cluster overview]

*Figure 1: Cluster overview*

All 3 instances in the cluster are in the same VPC, say: `vpc-123456`

Below are the `vpc-123456`'s settings of:

- Network ACL - Inbounds

[image]

- Network ACL - Outbounds

[image]

- Security groups - Inbounds

[image]

- Security groups - Outbounds

[image]

As you may have seen, for `Network ACL`, I accept all traffic for inbounds and outbounds while for `Security groups`, I accept traffic on port `3306` and leave open for outbounds.

But when I try to connect to the cluster using `Sequel Pro`, I got this error:

```
Unable to connect to host ... because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'Administrator'@'<my ip>' (using password: YES)
```

[image]

Where `Administrator` is the account that I am currently using to set up my cluster, as you can see at the upper right corner of `Figure 1`.

My questions:

1. Is is right to use `Administrator` to connect to the cluster using `Sequel Pro`? Or I have to create another IAM account?
2. The endpoint to connect to is `Writer` or `Reader` in *Figure 1*? I have tried all endpoints in both cluster and instances but nothing works.

I've been stuck with this for 2 days but still cannot find a solution.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me!!

`Administrator` account has nothing to do with this MySQL connection from `Sequel Pro`, instead, the account that was created during creating the cluster must be used!

Shoot! Waste 2 days of mine.

Thanks for reading.